# OpenCV boundary and intersection detection in a video

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I am obtaining a feed from my camera and an example frame from it looks as follows

[image: http://imgur.com/Tv7fb]

The frame consists of a boundary and a moving object. I have the following questions.

1) How do I dynamically detect the boundary efficiently? The boundary is guaranteed to be of a different color to the rest of the surroundings.

2) How do I detect the boundary of the moving object efficiently? It is guaranteed to be the only moving object in the frame.

3) How do I determine an intersection between the boundary and the moving object? The boundary and object could be in any shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use segmentation techniques to find large areas of solid color. Choose, say, the largest solid color region as your boundary. Or, use the [Hough transform](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) to find strong lines in the image, and identify the boundary.  Create a mask containing white pixels where your boundary region lies, black everywhere else.
2. Use [background subtraction](http://experienceopencv.blogspot.com/2011/01/background-subtraction-and-models.html).  This can be done in a simple way by capturing a reference frame with no objects in the scene, and then just subtracting it from subsequent frames. Create a mask containing white pixels where your object is, black everywhere else.
3. Intersect the masks created in 1 and 2 with a [per-element AND operation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and) (or a per-element multiply).

Comment: The boundary is just a colored tape forming either a straight line or a curved path. Can Hough transform be used to detect curved paths as well ?

Comment: It can but it's a little trickier, since you essentially have to parametrize that curve and test over a range of parameters. Sounds like a much better idea to detect by color in the Hue-Saturation-Value color space if at all possible.